# How to read a file name, locate it and open it through java

Tags: java, file-io

I have a file written that contains a list of GPS coordinates, it just has 2 columns longitude and latitude and that is it.
I have a second file that will contain the GPS coordinates text file name and a list of deviceId's, for example - `Routes_A.txt 285, 284`
What I have to do is write code to open the file and read it, which I can do;

```
File textA = new File("C:/Users/Daniel Dold/Desktop/Routes/Bus_Routes.txt");
Scanner scannerA = new Scanner(textA);
while(scannerA.hasNextLine())
    {
        String line = scannerA.nextLine();
        System.out.println(line);
    }
```

The problem I am having is I need to be able to open the Routes_A.txt file when the code opens the Bus_Routes.txt file, and not have it hard coded in my code.

Does anyone have any information that can help me?

Comment: What is your problem exactly? Splitting the line? Open a file?

Comment: I want to open the Bus_Routes.txt file, read the first line, see that its a text file name and then open the Routes_A.txt file so it can get at that information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse the line read from `Bus_Routes.txt` to extract the 2nd filename:

```
String line = scannerA.nextLine();
String[] parsed = line.split("\\s"); //split at whitespace
String otherFileName = parsed[0];    //other filename was 1st part of line

File dir = //what directory are the files in?
File otherFile = new File(dir, otherFileName);
//now read this file the same way as you read the previous one
```